# "Our meeting tomorrow Tuesday" versus "Our meeting tomorrow (Tuesday)"

Tags: grammar, dates

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- How about we postpone our meeting tomorrow Tuesday?
- How about we postpone our meeting tomorrow (Tuesday)?

I would also be interested in alternative formulations to express the fact that tomorrow is Tuesday (without significantly altering the sentence structure), which I do to avoid any possible confusion on which day is tomorrow. The confusion may arise if the sentence is present in an email sent around midnight, or if the recipient opens the email the day after.

Comment: If you mean that the meeting is tomorrow, which is a Tuesday, I think it would be much clearer to say "postpone tomorrow's meeting" because "postpone our meeting tomorrow" sounds like you're putting it off *until* tomorrow.  I'm not clear why it's important to emphasize that tomorrow is Tuesday - presumably everybody has a calendar - but "tomorrow Tuesday" isn't a standard English construction.  It might be clearer to break it into two sentences or a parenthetical, like "We have a meeting scheduled for tomorrow (Tuesday the 9th)..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are times when it is useful to say both the relative day (tomorrow) and and absolute day (Tuesday), and this is usually in an email situation when it not determinable when the email will be read.

It might be written as

> How about we postpone our meeting tomorrow (Tuesday, 22nd), until...?

However in conversation or when context is well understood, it is often expressed as

> How about we postpone *tomorrow's meeting*?

in which case "*our*" is redundant.

Comment: This is exactly how I would have answered the question. One could also put the month and date inside the parentheses, e.g.: _How about we postpone our meeting tomorrow (Tuesday, May 9) until Thursday, May 11?_ (This is just another way to write it out; both ways work just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

You would not usually use both "tomorrow" and the name of the day of the week in the same sentence.  It's assumed people know what day is tomorrow.  If not – it happens – they will ask.

Otherwise your statement is ambiguous. Do you want to postpone tomorrow's meeting, or postpone today's meeting until tomorrow?

> How about we postpone our meeting tomorrow (until next Tuesday)?
>
> How about we postpone our meeting until tomorrow?

As I said, sometimes people forget what day it is.

> A: How about we postpone our meeting until tomorrow?
>   B: What day is today?
>   A: Monday
>   B: OK, so postpone until tomorrow, Tuesday.  Got it.